# Provide GitHub file as default conf file in a docker-compose volume

Tags: docker, github, docker-compose

So my question is whether it is possible to have a volume like:

`"${my_conf_file}:-raw.my/GitHub/file.git":/conf.json`

So this would be my goal, however I do not find anything related to this. In the end if the user has a file, the file should be passed, otherwise either conf.json should not be replaced by anything (because the GitHub file is already there, to be replaced by a conf file that a user might have) or the file from GitHub should be passed again.

Answer (score 0):

If it best to figure out the first part (`"${my_conf_file}:-raw.my/GitHub/file.git"`) ahead of the `docker run`.

In your start script (which calls `docker run` or uses your `docker-compose.yml`), add a script able to determine which config file you want (the user's, conf.json itself or the one from GitHub)

Once you can script that, then you can add your `docker run -v` call, which will mount the right file to `:/conf.json` in the container.

Comment: The problem is, I don't have a start script, the idea was to have a docker-compose to facilitate the distribution where the user would only have to docker-compose up the project

Comment: @magp indeed, in that context, a start script is not ideal. I didn't see any special syntax in docker-compose itself which would support what you are asking.